# Quantizing OpenCV dnn calibration data error

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, pytorch, quantization

I am attempting to run

```
net =  cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX(onnx_model_path) 
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)
net.quantize(dummy_input, 'CV_32F', 'CV_8S')
```

And I get

```
error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'quantize'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'calibData'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol
>  - Can't parse 'calibData'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol
```

How do I provide the calibration data to quantize the dnn object correctly?

Comment: try giving it **a list** of *numpy arrays* instead. it might tolerate a list of pytorch tensors, but it does want a list of things. -- the succeeding arguments **must not** be strings. it expects OpenCV types (`cv.CV_32F` and so on)

Comment: dummy_input = np.random.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)
net.quantize(dummy_input, cv2.CV_32F, cv2.CV_8S)

I am now getting
error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/layers/convolution_layer.cpp:404: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Number of input channels should be multiple of 3 but got 224 in function 'getMemoryShapes'

even for dummy_input = np.random.randn(1, 224, 224, 3)

Comment: did you read that I said you should try to pass a **list**, meaning `[dummy_input]` (yes, single-item list) and you need to remove the N dimension (first one)